# Nest JS: TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key? when using with injection token

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, passport.js, nestjs-jwt

I want to create an auth module as a separate node package so that we can reuse it for multiple projects.

AS part of it we want to supply the necessary config from the main app via AuthLibModule. register() which supplies this param as config.

and the passed config will be held using an injection token to use it via dependency injection.

HOW DO WE ACHIEVE IT?

AuthLib.module.ts

```
@Module({})
export class AuthLibModule {

  static register(config: AuthLibConfig): DynamicModule {
    const authConfigToken = {
      provide: AuthLibConstants.JWT_CONFIG_TOKEN,
      useValue: config.jwtConfig
    };
    return {
      module: AuthLibModule,
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot(
          {
            isGlobal: true
          }
        ),
        MongooseModule.forRoot(config.mongoDbUrl ? config.mongoDbUrl : process.env.MONGO_URI),
        AuthModule
      ],
      controllers: [],
      exports: [authConfigToken],
      providers: [authConfigToken]
    }
  }
}
```

APP.MODULE.TS

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthLib.register({
        authTokenExpiration: 60S,
        authTokenSecret: XYZZZZZ,
        refreshTokenSecret: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY,
        refreshTokenExpiration: 90S
    })
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

jwt.strategy.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, GuardNames.jwtAuth) {
    constructor(
        @Inject(AuthLibConstants.JWT_CONFIG) jwtConfig: JWTConfig
    ) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: false,
        // jwtConfig.authTokenSecret -> getting as undefined.
            secretOrKey: jwtConfig.authTokenSecret
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: TokenParsePayload): Promise<TokenParsePayload> {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[Nest] 21492  - 28/02/2022, 5:30:03 pm   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] JwtStrategy requires a secret or key
TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key
    at new JwtStrategy (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\node_modules\passport-jwt\lib\strategy.js:45:15)
    at new MixinStrategy (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\passport\passport.strategy.js:32:13)
    at new JwtStrategy (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\src\auth\strategies\Jwt-auth.strategy.ts:17:9)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:301:19)
    at callback (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:48:41)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:124:24)
    at Injector.loadInstance (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:52:9)
    at Injector.loadProvider (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:74:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 6)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (D:\Freelancing\code-mentor\infra-services\auth-lib\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:44:9)
```

Comment: I've seen this same error message in several stack overflow posts before. Tell us, at least, what you've tried.

Comment: As I am trying to build auth lib as an external private package(which will be published to private npm repo and reuse in several projects). with this use case in mind, we want to supply the secret config values to auth-lib from the container app.
 
so in auth lib, I have exposed one injector token to supply config. and in jwtStrategy.ts file, I want to use the supplied secret value from the container app, instead of the local env file.

jwt.strategy.ts from the above code, the line below is not working.

secretOrKey: jwtConfig.authTokenSecret

it is working if we hardcode secret value

Comment: This was resolved by converting authModule as dynamic Module

<code>
@Module({})
export class AuthModule {
    static register(config: JWTConfig): DynamicModule {
        console.log(config);
        return {
            module: AuthModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: AuthLibConstants.JWT_CONFIG,
                    useValue: config
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
</code>

From AuthLib.Module.ts

<code> 
AuthModule.register({ ... })
</code>